# Is there any system or software that will allow a non-technical user to print pictures simply?

Tags: point-and-shoot, printing, workflow, computerless

My wife broke her point-and-shoot camera, so we're in the market for a replacement.

One of her friends has an older Kodak, and I believe it has a dock that is directly attached to a printer — something like that would be ideal, but I can't find any reference to it on the Kodak site.

Are there any cameras that come with a dedicated printing system for a reasonable price, or is there always going to be a computer required?

If a computer is required, what would be the simplest software for printing occasional pictures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any camera will do and you have several options for easy home printing.

If you do not want to involve a computer than **buy a printer which has memory card slots**. The ones I know and the one I own is from HP, other brand have them too. They are called Photosmart. Mine does not have a screen but the new ones do, so you can see your photo before printing and even do simple things to it like cropping, selecting print sizes, etc.

Mine is a multi-function model that does photo-copying, scanning and faxing. I was truly impressed the first time I used it. It has an **index print function which lets you print a thumbnail of all your photos and then you mark the ones you like, the size you want and how many copies.** Put the index print back into the fax part of the all-in-one and, guess what?, it prints the photos you want in the size you want and number of copies! That is certainly the best integration job I have ever seen from ANY technology company.

Some cameras have a direct print function which lets you attach the camera to a printer directly. I have never tried that since it both limits which cameras you can buy and which printers. I would much rather choose a good camera based on photographic merits and a printer based on quality.

Comment: Sadly, we have a Photosmart printer with the memory slots, but that's not simple enough apparently.

Comment: It is pretty simple with the Canon PIXMA MP560, though.

Comment: Oh. You may want to check other models directly in a store or on HP's website, they have video demos for some. Mine is already 2 years old and I need to press 2 buttons to get any number of prints out. Hopefully they are working on mind-reading printers as the next logical step ;)